# Problems with looping multiple combinations of variables in linear models for different series

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I'm having an issue I think it can be easily solvable, however I'm not being able to find the answer to it.

I have an excel file that contains a certain amount of columns containing traffic series (T1, T2) with certain independent variables (V1, V2, V3) to which I have to build all possible combinations of linear models. I have been able to do it in a slow manner, however I've been asked to optimize with a loop and that's where I'm struggling.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
rep.example<-data.frame(V1=rnorm(25,15),V2=rnorm(25,5),V3=runif(25,0.4),T1=rnorm(25,12),T2=rnorm(25,35))

ind.vars = c("V1","V2","V3")

Comb.Matrix <- expand.grid(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, FALSE))
names(Comb.Matrix) <- ind.vars

Comb.Matrix <- Comb.Matrix[-(dim(Comb.Matrix)[1]),]


allModelsList       <- apply(Comb.Matrix,
                             1,
                             function(x) as.formula(paste(c(" T1 ~ ",
                                                            ind.vars[x]), collapse = " + ")))
```

This creates a list with all possible combinations of linear models for Traffic Series T1. However, I have data where sometimes I may have several columns of traffic series and I'd like the model to iterate over the columns so it would store all combinations in lists. I tried adding the following to the code:

```
Series <- c("T1", "T2")

for (i in 1:length(Series)){
  allModelsList <- apply(Comb.Matrix,
                         1,
                         function(x) as.formula(paste(c(Series[i]," ~ ",
                                                        ind.vars[x]), 
                                                      collapse = " + ")))
}
```

I'd like for it to go to every value of Series and make all possible combinations with that value in the form of ' T1 ~ Var Combinations'  and the same for T2 and more eventual columns....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around it by doing the following:

```
allModelsList=list()

for (i in 1:length(Series)){
  allModelsList <- append(
    allModelsList, 
    apply(Comb.Matrix, 1, function(x) as.formula(paste(c(paste(" ", Series[i], " ~ "), ind.vars[x]), collapse = " + ")))
  )
}
```

For every index/column in "Series" the model performs all possible combinations of variables.